# How to use datediff sql function in nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am developing an application to test execution time SQL queries using different frameworks. I have some problem to write one of the queries using Fluent nHibernate. The query should return all employees that are older than 50 years. In some page I found the DateProjections class which I attach below.

```
public static class DateProjections
    {
        private const string DateDiffFormat = "datediff({0}, ?1, ?2)";

        public static IProjection DateDiff(
            string datepart,
            Expression<Func<object>> startDate,
            Expression<Func<object>> endDate)
        {
            // Build the function template based on the date part.
            string functionTemplate = string.Format(DateDiffFormat, datepart);

            return Projections.SqlFunction(
                new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Int32, functionTemplate),
                NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                Projections.Property(startDate),
                Projections.Property(endDate));
        }
    }
```

The function to get employees is the following:

```
public List<EmployeeAgeViewModel> GetEmployeesOlderThan50()
        {
            Person personAlias = null;
            EmployeeAgeViewModel result = null;

            var temp = _session.QueryOver<Employee>().JoinQueryOver(x => x.Person, () => personAlias).SelectList(
                list => list
                .Select(x => personAlias.FirstName).WithAlias(() => result.FirstName)
                .Select(x => personAlias.LastName).WithAlias(() => result.LastName)
                .Select(x => x.Gender).WithAlias(() => result.Gender)
                .Select(x => x.BirthDate).WithAlias(() => result.BirthDate)
                .Select(x => x.HireDate).WithAlias(() => result.HireDate)
                .Select(DateProjections.DateDiff("yy", () => personAlias.Employee.BirthDate, () => DateTime.Now)).WithAlias(() => result.Age)
                )
                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<EmployeeAgeViewModel>())
                .List<EmployeeAgeViewModel>();

            return temp.ToList();
```

The problem is probably the way I am passing BirthDate property and DateTime.Now to DateDiff function. In the personAlias variable the Employee property is null - maybe I should assign it somehow before - any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `BirthDate` a property of `Employee` or `Person`? If it's really a property of `Employee` I suggest that you use an `employeeAlias` by doing this: `_session.QueryOver<Employee>(() => employeeAlias)` and `DateProjections.DateDiff("yy", () => employeeAlias.BirthDate`

Comment: Yes, perfect answer! The employee alias in parenthesis was missing. I spent a lot of time digging what may be wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I put my comment into an answer, so that your question doesn't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `personAlias.Employee.BirthDate` you need to use an `employeeAlias`.

Your code with the necessary changes looks like this:

```
Person personAlias = null;
Employee employeeAlias = null;
EmployeeAgeViewModel result = null;

var temp = _session.QueryOver<Employee>(() => employeeAlias)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Person, () => personAlias)
    .SelectList(
        list => list
        .Select(x => personAlias.FirstName).WithAlias(() => result.FirstName)
        .Select(x => personAlias.LastName).WithAlias(() => result.LastName)
        .Select(x => x.Gender).WithAlias(() => result.Gender)
        .Select(x => x.BirthDate).WithAlias(() => result.BirthDate)
        .Select(x => x.HireDate).WithAlias(() => result.HireDate)
        .Select(DateProjections.DateDiff("yy", () => employeeAlias.BirthDate, () => DateTime.Now))
            .WithAlias(() => result.Age)
        )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<EmployeeAgeViewModel>())
    .List<EmployeeAgeViewModel>();

return temp.ToList();
```